# how to extract the column in a dataframe with the values matching to a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, i have a data.frame like (the first row is the name of the data frame)：

```
A  B  C  D
a  i  e  e
a  e  i  o
a  a  i  i
i  -  a  m
a  -  a  m
```

I have a vector `cc= c('a', 'e', 'i')`, and I want to extract the columns in the dataframe with the values only contain in the vector `cc`, since `B` and `D` columns contain values which is not in the `cc`, so they should be excluded, and the desired result should look like

```
    A    C  
    a    e  
    a    i  
    a    i  
    i    a  
    a    a
```

I try the codes:

```
apply(df, 2 , function(x) x%in% cc)
```

But the outcome will be

```
 A     B     C     D
TRUE  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
TRUE  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
TRUE  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
```

I got stuck here and could anyone tell me what can I do next in r?

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah, I just construct a data frame like that to show my problem

Comment: You are almost there. You need to use `all` in your `apply` function to get the TRUE value for the columns which contains all the value from `cc` vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
df1[sapply(df1, function(x) all(x %in% cc))]
```

---

Or with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) all(x %in% cc), df1)
#  A C
#1 a e
#2 a i
#3 a i
#4 i a
#5 a a
```

Comment: Thank you@akrun, it works! I will accept your solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative -- use `anyNA` along with `match`:

```
mydf[vapply(mydf, function(x) !anyNA(match(x, cc)), logical(1L))]
##   A C
## 1 a e
## 2 a i
## 3 a i
## 4 i a
## 5 a a
```